# Recursion How Does This Find The Max?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

can someone explain how the line `restMax = max(A[1:])` finds the max element in an array? I know it's breaking it down into subarrays each time, but how does this find the max?

```
def max(A):
     if len(A)==0 :
        return None
     if len(A)==1 :
        return A[0]
     restMax = max(A[1:])
     if A[0]>restMax :
        return A[0]
     return restMax
```

Comment: The `max` of the list is the larger of the first element and the `max` of the remaining elements (if any). What exactly is not clear about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursive functions can be tricky at first, so let's go through what this function does:

If `max(A)` is called on an empty array, it returns none.

```
if len(A)==0 :
    return None
```

If `max(A)` is called on an array with a single element, it returns that element:

```
if len(A)==1 :
    return A[0]
```

If `max(A)` is called on an array with more than one element, it does the following:

- It splits `A` into two: the first element (the head, `A[0]`) and the other elements (the tail, `A[1:]`).
- It finds out what the maximum of the tail is recursively (`max(A[1:])`, the tricky part).
- If the head is bigger than the tail's max, it returns the head. Otherwise it returns the tail's max.

### Putting it all together:

Let's go over what `max([1,4,7,2])` looks like:

- (1) `[1,4,7,2]` has several elements, so we split it in two: `1` and `[4,7,2]`. Let's find out what `max([4,7,2])` is:

  - (2) `[4,7,2]` is split into `4` and `[7,2]`. Let's find out what `max([7,2])` is.

    - (3) `[7, 2]` is split into `7` and `[2]`. Let's find out what `max([2])` is.

      - (4) `[2]` has one element, so `max([2])` returns `2`.
    - Now we're back at (3). We compare `7` and `max([2])` which returned `2`. `7` is bigger, so `max([7,2])` returns `7`.
  - Now we're back at (2). We compare `4` and `max([7,2])`, which we've seen that returned `7`. Since `7` is bigger that `4`, we return `7`.
- Now we're back at (1). We had split our original array into `1` and `[4,7,2]`. `max([4,7,2])` returned `7`, so we compare `1` and `7`. `7` is bigger, so `max([1,4,7,2])` returns `7`.

We're done! `max([1,4,7,2])` is 7.